# How to solve this differential equation $y'' = (y')^3-(y')^2$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It is in fact an initial value problem:

$$
y'' = (y')^3-(y')^2
$$

with $$y(0) = 3$$ and $$y'(0) = 1$$

I did check the final answer and it is quite simple, but I don't know how to arrive that. Thanks.

Comment: Assuming $y' \ne 0$, the equation can be written as $$\frac{y''}{y'^{2}} - y' = 1$$ Then note that $$\frac{y''}{y'^{2}} = - \left( \frac{1}{y'} \right)'$$

Comment: Substitution $z=y'$, $z'=y''$?

Comment: @MatthewCassell I tried the substitution $v = 1/y'$ and got a similar equation $v' = 1 - 1/v$, and solving it got $v + ln(v-1) = x + c$, but I can't substitude $v(0) = 1 / y'(0) = 1$ to find c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $y':=z$ and by chain of rule we have
$$y''=z'=\frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{dz}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}=z\frac{dz}{dy}.$$
Then, the ODE can be written as
$$z\frac{dz}{dy}=z^{3}+z^{2}$$
i.e., $$\frac{z}{z^{3}+z^2}dz=dy$$
Integration give $$\log(1-z)-\log(z)=y+A$$
where $A$ is not known constant and we are assuming that all the functions are well-defined, seems there is not problem by the initial condition,  so continue. Rewriting all, we have

$$\log\left(\frac{1}{z}-1\right)=y+A$$
Applying the composition with the mapping $x\mapsto e^{x}$, we have
$$\frac{1}{z}-1=Ae^{y}$$
Substitution back $y':=z$ and rewriting we have
$$y'=\frac{1}{1+Ae^{y}}$$
Since $y(0):=3$, we have
$$\int_{3}^{y}(1+Ae^{s})ds=\int_{0}^{x}d\tau$$
give $$A(e^{y}-e^{3})+y-3=x$$
or alternatively use the indefinite integrals and then impose the initial condition. In this case, we can apply implicit differentiation and we have
$$Ae^{y}-0+y'+0=1$$
i.e., $$y'=1-Ae^{y}$$Impose the condition over the derivative $y'(0):=1$ and we have $1=1-Ae^{y}$ and then $A=0$. Therefore we arrived
$$0(e^{y}-e^{3})+y-3=x$$
i.e., $$y=x+3$$
is a particular solution of the initial value problem.

Answer (score 0):

@alexander-xander posted the right answer which is inspiring. I just do it one more time for my own clarity.

Let $v = y'$, we have:
$$y'' = \frac{dv}{dx} = \frac{dv}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx} = v \frac{dv}{dy}$$
This is a common technique for solving second order ODE with indepedent variable $x$ missing in the equation.

So, the equation becomes

$$v\frac{dv}{dy} = (v)^3 - (v)^2$$
$$\frac{1}{v^2 - v}\frac{dv}{dy} = 1$$
$$\int\frac{1}{v-1}-\frac{1}{v} dv = \int dy$$
$$ln(v-1)-ln(v)=y+k$$

Given $v(0) = y'(0) = 1$ and $y(0) = 3$, we can't substitude that to the above as $ln(0)$ is not defined. However, if we take $e$ to the power of both sides:

$$\frac{v-1}{v} = e^ke^y$$

and let $A = e^k$, and substitude $v = 1$ and $y = 3$ into the equation, we have:

$$Ae^3 = \frac{(1) - 1}{(1)} = 0$$
$$A = 0$$
(which is impossible to solve if we keep $e^k$ as $e^k > 0$ for all $k$).

So, that means:

$$\frac{v - 1}{v} = 0$$
$$v = \frac{dy}{dx} = 1$$
$$y = x + c$$

By substituding $y(0) = 3$, $c = 3$, so the solution is:

$$y = x + 3$$